# Git. Синхронизация данных. Как мне подключить удалённый репозиторий к локальному

Tags: git, gitlab

Переустанавливал систему. Все настройки git`a слетели, у меня осталась папка c проектом. В ней уже сделал большой набор изменений. Как мне подключить эту папку к удалённому репозиторию?
Спасибо!

Comment: Склонируйте репозиторий в другую папку, а потом скопируйте туда с заменой папку текущего проекта.

Comment: @Suvitruf, похоже так и придётся. Добавьте как ответ - отмечу. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Склонировать в другую папку.
2. Из текущей папки удалить папку **.git**
3. Скопировать с заменой локальный проект поверх склонированного.